# Show record if a value is not found in another query

Tags: ms-access

I have a table [class_attendance_tbl] showing class attendance for a class that a client could attend or even miss multiple times. The record shows the [client_id], the [class_session_id], the [class_date], and if they attended the class [attended] which is a yes or no function. They might have 3-4 records of the same [class_session_id] from missing that same session multiple times but once they attend that class session it will be put on the same table again but with the [attended] marked as TRUE.

I have another table [session_list_tbl] that simply shows how many sessions are in each class, this lists the [session_id]'s for each class we are working with.

I also have two queries, one query [classes_attended_q] that shows which classes they attended, it simply looks for [attended] to be marked as true. this works fine.

The second query [classes_remaining] is the problem. I want it to look at the [class_session_id] of the [session_list_tbl] and list them all WITH the condition that the client HAS NOT completed that class. So if the [class_session_id] is listed in the [class_attendance_tbl] with the [attendance] field marked as TRUE then I DO NOT want it to show in the query. I just want to see which sessions that client needs to attend in the list of sessions for that class.

Sorry if this was too long, I tried to provide as much detail while still making it brief.

Comment: Please show table structures at a minimum, with a preference that you show what SQL you've tried and why it's not returning what you're expecting.  Keep in mind that SO is merely a site where we try to help each other, but we all have jobs (or school) and no one is paid to be here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly...but perhaps you could try to define your second query something like this:

Make it a select query on the "class_attendance_tbl"

The first field in the query would be "class_session_id"

The second field would be "attended"

In the query design window, click the sigma/totals button in the "Show/Hide" section of the ribbon

For "class_session_id," select "group by" as the "Total" option

For "attended," select "sum" as the total option and enter "false" as the "criteria" option

Running the query should select all class_session_id entries for which it is true that each and every instance in you table shows an "attended" value of false.

[image]